# Limits and Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, graph-limits

In my maths textbook, for the theory of limits, there is a statement which I am not able to make intuitive sense of. It says:

> At a given point, the value of a function and its limit may be different, even when both are well defined.

Can someone please explain this and give an example for such a function? What is the usefulness of limits in such a case, when the entire concept of limits is based on approaching a real number and being able to give it a value?

Comment: The simplest example is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=0\\0&\text{if }x\neq 0\end{cases}$$ The use of limits is (partly) so we can exclude cases like this. The origin of calculus and limits is to describe motion, where such functions tend not to exist. Mathematically, they exist, but they are not a useful way to describe motion.

Comment: “… when the entire concept of limits is based on approaching a real number and being able to give it a value?” Often, the function doesn’t have a value. Even when there is a value, there might be another value for the function at that $x$ which is “nicer.”

Comment: Okay, I understood how the function behaves over a graph and how there is a difference between the limit and how the function is defined. But how does the concept of limit helps to exclude this function?

Comment: A function is continuous if the limits agree with its values. From the graph you can clearly see the discontinuity in the example given by @ThomasAndrews which is why it fails. The limits as you approach zero is zero, but $f(0)=1$ so they disagree. This identifies the discontinuity and if the limit and the function differ at a point it will always have some sort of discontinuity there.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)\neq f(0),$ so $f$ is what is called “discontinuous at $0.$” Often, when we have theorems about continuous functions, which are not true for discontinuous functions. Defining limits lets us define “continuous/discontinuous,” which in turn allows us to talk about the class of functions we want to talk about.

Comment: Note, graphs themselves can be a misleading intuition for functions, because there are functions which cannot be (intuitively) drawn because they are so discontinuous. The intuition of a graph is a function that is “mostly continuous.” A function that is $1$ on the rational numbers and $0$ otherwise is very hard to visualize as a graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas Andrews and CyclotomicField, for the additional clarification on continous and discontinous functions. I got what the original statement meant to say.